# How to take certain number of elements from Array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

Ok so I have a frontend that displays cards. The information comes from my GraphQL api.It makes the request and sends the props to a card component. I have different size cards. I want the first 3 elements from the array to go to the small cards and then the rest to go to the big cards. How can I do this?

The react code I have right now is:

```
           {loading ? (
              <h1>Loading Campaigns...</h1>
            ) : (
              data && data.campaigns.map(campaign => (
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} key={campaign.id}>
              <Card campaign={campaign} cbody = {campaign.body} title = {campaign.title}
              
              />
              </Grid>
              ) )
            )}
```

Campaign is basically each element in the array.

Comment: See [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: `data && data.campaigns.map((campaign, index) => )` - Render your card based on the index.

Answer (score 0):

Use `slice` like:

```
data.campaigns.slice(0,3).map(...)
```

So you will end up with two maps for that case, but that's fine.

Or you could use the index of the current `map` and check if the `index` is less than 3, and do conditional rendering there directly

Answer (score 0):

> Using index inside map

```
data && data.campaigns.map((campaign, index) => {return /*condtional rendering here*/} )
```

> using slice

**First three**

```
data && data.campaigns.slice(0,3).map( item => /*render here*/)
```

**rest**

```
data && data.campaigns.slice(3).map( item => /*render here*/)
```